# how to select mysql two colume take last 200 id order desc, then get 5 order by counter desc for best performace

Tags: php, mysql

my table keep million records.
i just want to extract the 5 most counter rows in last 200 rows.

Im using this but as i thinking this is two time select .. that may not right for best performace plase advice.

```
"select * from (
            select sid,title,catid,counter from table_stories 
                where catid=1 order by sid desc limit 200
            ) astemps order by counter desc limit 5"
```

thanks very much..
regards

Comment: The query looks fine to me. To get good performance make sure you've got indexes on those columns. Use `EXPLAIN [query]` to see if MySQL uses the index.

Answer (score 1):

This is your query:

```
select *
from (select sid, title, catid, counter
      from table_stories 
      where catid = 1
      order by sid desc
      limit 200
     ) astemps
order by counter desc
limit 5;
```

For optimal performance, you want an index on `table_stories(catid, sid desc)`.  You can throw `title` and `counter` into the index, but they won't help much.  Unfortunately, MySQL may not take advantage of the descending key for to replace the sort.